# SQL Inner join and Not in

Tags: sql, join, select

I am trying to run a query and not sure why the returned record set is off by 60 rows.

```
Select t1.*  into #temp1
from NameExt as t1
 join #temp1 as t2
on t1.AN = t2.AN --164172

Select t1.* into #temp3 
from NameExt as t1
where AN in (Select AN from #temp1) --164112
```

When I do an intersect or except on #temp1 and #temp2, I dont get any rows back.

Really need to understand why the two queries are returning not a similar record set.

Even this returns the same number of rows as the 2nd query

```
Select * into #temp3 from NameExt as t1  where exists 
 ( Select 1 from #temp1 as t2 where t1.AN = t2.AN) --164112
```

Thanks much

Comment: It has to do with the number of records in each table with a particular value. I'm guessing there's a duplicate value in `#temp1.AN` that matches `NameExt.AN`. This would give you the extra rows in the JOIN-based query.

Comment: Could you run the query without inserting data into `#temp1`? `Select Count(t1.*) from ...`

Comment: Yesm your right, there were duplicate records in one of the tables. Thanks for much for pointing me in the right direction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can easily see what values are causing problems by doing:

```
select t2.AN
from #temp1  t2
group by t2.AN
having count(*) > 1;
```

Duplicates in the second table are causing the problem.  You know how to fix it . . . using `in` or `exists`.

Comment: Thanks much that did it, there were duplicates in one of the tables.

Answer (score 0):

Your query is incorrect. You cannot select from and create a temp table at the same time..

Select t1.*  into  **#temp1**
from NameExt as t1
 join **#temp1** as t2
on t1.AN = t2.AN --164172

Answer (score 0):

As per a comment, you likely have multiple rows in `#temp1` with the same value in `AN`...

```
   CREATE TABLE x (
     id   INT
   )

   CREATE TABLE y (
     id   INT,
     x_id INT
   )

   INSERT INTO x VALUES (1),    (2),    (3)
   INSERT INTO y VALUES (1, 2), (2, 2), (3, 3)

   SELECT *
   FROM x INNER JOIN y ON x.id = y.x_id

   -- a total of three rows

   -- x.id | y.id | y.x_id
   ------------------------
   --  2   |  1   |   2
   --  2   |  2   |   2
   --  3   |  3   |   3

   SELECT *
   FROM x
   WHERE x.id IN (SELECT y.x_id FROM y)

   -- a total of two rows

   -- x.id
   --------
   --  2
   --  3
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/7e1d1/2